# Nested strtok() calls to tokenize given string does not work as expected

Tags: c, nested-loops, c-strings, strtok, null-pointer

I want to tokenize a provided input string using `strtok()`. In the first step, I want to tokenize the given string by "|" symbol. Then, I tokenize each substring by ";". Finally, I tokenize the resulting substrings by " "(empty char).  At the end, I aim to obtain an array of string arrays.

However, my while loop iterates just one time so I cannot process the whole string. All I get is:

I duplicate substrings before I pass them to `strtok()` but it does not work. I have spent almost 3 days but I could not achieve it yet. Any help will be greatly appreciated. For more detail, I provide the code and the output I receive.

Output:
cat
my_books.txt[enter image description here

Comment: Instead of the function strtok use function strtok_s.

Comment: Please also don't post pictures of text. Copy'n'paste the text instead. That said, it works exactly as expected, at least to me.

Answer (score 1):

The function `strtok` has a static local variable (pointer) that stores the last position of the parsed string within the function.

For example after the inner most loop

```
while (token3 != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", token3);
    token3 = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

the static variable will be equal to NULL. So all outer loops will stop their iterations.

Instead use function `strtok_s` for which you can specify an argument that will keep the last position in the parsed string.

The function is declared like

```
char *strtok_s(char * restrict s1,
               rsize_t * restrict s1max,
               const char * restrict s2,
               char ** restrict ptr);
```

So for each loop you can declare a pointer like for example

```
char *pos;
```

and pass it to the function as expression `&pos`.

Comment: `strtok_s()` on POSIX systems is likely not implemented - there aren't many mainstream implementations of C-standard-compliant `strtok_s()`.  `glibc`, for example, doesn't implement it (at least the one on my Ubuntu laptop doesn't...).  And Microsoft's `strtok_s()` implementation doesn't comply with the C11 Annex K specification and is actually equivalent to POSIX `strtok_r()`.

Comment: Windows systems should use `strtok_s()` and POSIX systems should use `strtok_r()` — the signatures are the same apart from the spelling of the function name.  The Annex K `strtok_s()` is different from either the Windows or POSIX functions — it has a fourth argument and is more complex to use.  Fortunately, you're unlikely to find an implementation of it in the wild.